# how to do performance testing of fix protocol

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, neoload

I need to do FIX-API based performance testing. 
Can you please let me know few way ahead.

Also if I need to develop the in-house plugin then please can you point in some direction that how to do that?

Also does any 3rd party tool like loadrunner or neoload directly support FIX-API protocol testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times before in many different forums.  Please leverage Google for keywords of LoadRunner and FIX for FIXML as aprpopriate

Comment: I am sorry but not getting much help by that. do you have some pointer please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a test in FIX protocol over a FIX connection you can try using the [FIXRobot](https://quickfixrobot.github.io/). [FIXRobot](https://quickfixrobot.github.io/) allows to easily write the tests in python. You can include a loop in the test script to pump messages and calculate the perf statistics from your application logs writing some scripts.